# Deriving the equation for radial wave function

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

I'm trying to solve Schrodinger's equation of an exciton using the separation of variables method: $\psi = RY$. Here's the equation I've already derived:
$$
\frac{2\mu r^2}{\hbar^2}(E+\frac{e^2}{\epsilon r})+\frac{r^2}{R}\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial r^2}+\frac{r}{R}\frac{\partial R}{\partial r} = -\frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial^2Y}{\partial\theta^2}
$$
Where the radial wave function is $R = R(r)$ and angular part is $Y = Y(\theta)$. Since the two sides of the equation only depend on a single variable, they are both constants. I've found the angular part is
$$
Y_m(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{im\theta}
$$
I'm having trouble solving the left part to obtain the radial equation. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: What are you looking for in terms of "solving" the equation? It seems to me very unlikely that a closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions exists for this non-linear ODE; on the other hand the chances are extremely high that for a physically-important ODE, special functions have been invented to solve it. For instance your ODE is almost that of a Bessel function so I might start looking there.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Thanks, why it's off?

Comment: This looks to me very like a hydrogenic-like function.  Indeed, when massaged a tiny bit and plugged into *Mathematica*, it spits back Whittaker M and W functions, which simplify to the radial parts of hydrogen orbital functions for the right $l$ and $E$. Given the right boundary conditions, I suspect that's exactly what you would get.

Comment: You are solving a hydrogenic  atom in ***two*** dimensions?  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/544028/two-dimensional-hydrogen-atom

Comment: However, it's not exactly hydrogen it seems, so there'll be some work to do here.  What are the boundary conditions on `R`? Finite at 0 and zero at infinity?

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Yes! I'm solving the function for exciton (an 'hydrogen atom' in 2 dimensions) :)

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.43.1186